# I can't enter my fedora system

Tags: fedora, nvidia, vulkan

Yesterday I was messing around with android emulator setup. I tried some commands, but to be honest I don’t remember everything I did. Overall, it has something to do with video card driver settings. Among other things, I removed vulkan library.

After I restarted my computer, my login screen looks like that:
[image: here is how my login screen looks like now]
It’s different from what I had before, and there is no way I can enter my system. I press "enter" but nothing happens.

What options do I have to fix that? Can I enter my system somehow? Or can I recover it? Or can I install new fedora so that I can use all of the data and installed programs?

Comment: Press CRTL+ALT+F1 and go to the CLI. Log in and fix whatever you may have broken. E.g. reinstalling card driver etc.

Comment: Hmm, I’ve rolled back everything I could find in terminal history, but still no luck. What if I just upgrade to fedora 34, what do you think?

Comment: Impossible to give a solid answer when not even you know what you did. Did you restart inbetween? Is your data (e.g. /home) on a separate partition? In that case a fresh install is one possibility without data loss.